# Proving GCD algorithm terminates

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

I'm reading this article on a GCD algorithm described by Dijkstra:
https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD03xx/EWD316.4.html

I'm looking at program 1.  In particular I'm trying to understand the proof that the loop terminates.  Here is program 1 (my notation is slightly different than the one in the article):

```
function GCD(a,b) 

while a != b
    if a > b 
        a = a - b
    else
        b = b - a

return a
```

I get that max(a,b) at loop n is strictly greater than max(a,b) at loop n+1.  Since a and b are integers greater than 0 it follows that max(a,b) is always greater than 0.  This implies a lower bound.  Therefore the while loop must terminate.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: if a=1 and b=-1 the algorithm wil not terminate. If a,b are positive integers then the max(a,b) will strictly decrease.

Comment: The algorithm doesn't terminate if a ≤ 0 or b ≤ 0 unless initially a = b.

Answer (score 1):

If you just care about termination of the algorithm not the tight analysis then you can say that it will terminates within $a+b$ steps as inside the while loop you are decreasing either $a$ or $b$ depending on some condition, so your while loop have to terminate within $a+b$ iterations.

Comment: Note that you're always decreasing the *larger* of `a` and `b`, so you can give a tighter bound than this.

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming that you start with positive integers**, your reasoning is correct. `max(a,b)` strictly decreases and the loop will terminate before this value reaches zero (since the only way for it to become zero is if `a == b`). Therefore it can run for at most `max(a,b)-1` steps

If you don't start with positive integers, then you'll loop forever. So make sure to avoid that.